# Function that polymorphically handles vector and hash_set

Tags: c++, stl, vector, polymorphism, hashset

I have function in C++ that takes a vector and pushes some items onto it. For example:

```
void MyFunction(vector<int>* output);
```

I want to modify it to be able to now take a vector **or** a hash_set.  In Java, this would be easy, simply change the function to take a Collection (the common interface).  All `MyFunction` does is put elements into the container it is given, so it shouldn't have to care whether that container is a vector or a hash_set, only that there is some notion of "inserting" an element.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The function takes a pointer, not a vector.

Comment: You might want to make the function take a reference to your vector instead so your usage is simpler within the function - but that's just a guess :)  It is possible that the pointer is better given your code, just not as likely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He'd have a small issue doing a straight-up template. Vector typically uses push_back while hash_set would use insert.

Use a template, but use the insert function and insert at the .end() element so that the vector maintains fast operations - its your best bet.  You'll still slow down your hash-set a little though if it takes the insertion position as a hint of location (it'll work though).

Using insert(iter, val), the contianer is extended by inserting new elements before the element at the iterator position.  This is true for sequence containers (vector) while associative containers (hash_set) will just use the position as a hint - but the insertion will still work fine.  The function below could be used to insert value U into any container supporting insert (all STL ones do) assuming U is the same as or implicitly convertible to the vector element type.

```
template <typename T, typename U>
void InsertToContainer(T& container, U val)
{
    container.insert(container.end(), val);
}
```

Comment: Yup :) some associative containers take insertion location as a hint of where to start looking for the ordering position though which is why I said it might slow down the map if you told it to look at the end first.

Comment: `x.insert(t, x.end())` should work for every container and also be pretty efficient. The slow-down for a wrong hint is negligible.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, You can use **[Boost::Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/variant.html)**

Comment: You'd want to stick a container in a boost variant?

Comment: @Tony: OP's function is taking an pointer to containers, not the containers itself.

Answer (score 0):

A function template would allow you to make it more generic:

```
 template<typename T, typename Cont = std::vector<T> > void MyFunction(T t, Cont c);
```

Here the default container would be `std::vector<T>`, but you could still change the container if you wanted to.

Comment: This only works if the type of the collection is known at compile time! I think the search for a solution at run time

Comment: Yes, but the simple problem is that functions are called differently (`push_back` vs `insert`) and have different signatures. Maybe the insert function as template parameter?

Comment: std::vector has a insert function, too

Comment: @Fox32 Yes, but it behaves differently (from the non-iterator `hash_set::insert`). Although you can just insert at `end()`, I don't know if this is the best idea to do on a `hash_set`, as it should take this as a hint and I don't know if that hint is allowed to be `end()`. But according to w00te's answer and its comments, my fears seem to have been without reason and `insert` is just fine.

Comment: You could technically resolve this, `insert` vs `push_back` problem using SFINAE, but I'm not good enough with templates yet to write you an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use methods that are not common between the two containers, you can create two derived wrapper classes with a pure virtual base class that defines a common interface for operations you would like to-do with a `unordered_set` and a `vector` that do not have simliar method names, and then pass pointers or references to the base-class to the function.

For instance, your pure virtual base-class can define methods for inserting, finding, iterating, etc., and can mask the differences in the method names and uses of the methods between these two containers that perform these types of operations.  Your derived types would be the actual implementation of the pure virtual methods in the base-class.  Your function would take a reference or pointer to the base-type, and since the base-class is polymorphic, you can just call the interface methods that the base-class defines, and use both `vector` and `unordered_set` with your function without worrying about implementation differences and interface mis-matches between linear containers and associative containers.